# Possible bug in siunitx package when using behind underscores

Tags: math-mode, siunitx, underscore

I use TeXstudio 2.12.22. Compiling this MWE

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
    Some text $test_\SI{4}{\km}$.
\end{document}
```

will throw the errors:

```
line 5: Missing { inserted. Some text $test_\SI
line 5: Missing } inserted. Some text $test_\SI{4}{\km}$
```

I have tested this with the document classes `scrbook` and `scrartcl` as well.

When combining the code with the `\text` command from the `amsmath` package, everything works, correctly:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    Some text $test_\text{\SI{4}{\km}}$.
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the latter MWE]

Did I find a bug, Joseph Wright?

Comment: Try with an extra set of `{}` around the `\SI` command: `$test_{\SI{4}{\km}}$`. Even if something like `$A_4$` gives the desired result, subscripts should always be enclosed in a set of `{}` as follows: `$A_{4}$`

Comment: No bug: complex subscripts should *always* be braced. If you're used to `_\mathrm{x}`, change your habits and type `_{\mathrm{x}}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Math mode `_` *looks* like it is taking 'stuff' as an argument in the construct

```latex
$a_\text{b}$
```

or similar, but this is not the case. Rather, the ability to omit braces in some cases is due to how `\text` and similar expand. That is *not generally true*, and official LaTeX syntax is to *require* braces here in all cases.

In the case of `siunitx`, the expansion behaviour of the document commands was never intended to 'fool' `_` into working. You should add the (standard) braces

```latex
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    Some text $test_{\SI{4}{\km}}}$.
\end{document}
```